# class not found Relative Layout error in React native app

Tags: react-native, android-layout, android-relativelayout

is there anyone who can please tell about this error is started after I set splash screen to my react native app.

my app was working before I added splash screen, I think there is something wrong in launch_screen.xml file in layout folder.
[open error SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDr1r.jpg)

Comment: Hi, welcome. If you think something is wrong in the file, please paste the code in so others can see what you're seeing. Check [ask] and how to make a [mcve]

Comment: I solved this issue. Check the answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76773115/relativelayout-error-from-textinput-and-launch-screen-file/76879105#76879105](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76773115/relativelayout-error-from-textinput-and-launch-screen-file/76879105#76879105)

Answer (score 1):

as long as you didn't show your code but said your app was working before you added the splash screen.

I think you can try one of these; both of them worked for me.

1. I was pointing the`XML` (lunch_screen) in my style, but when I commented or changed it to `@drawable/rn_edit_text_material` it works fine

   @drawable/rn_edit_text_material

`<item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item`

2.as mentioned in the [guide](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) add these to your `style.xml`

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```